# Windows 10 Kiosk Mode with ADK - Task Manager Bypassing

Tags: windows, configuration, windows-10, kiosk-mode, kiosk

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on configuring a Windows 10 Enterprise VM using the ADK for Windows 10 to set up a kiosk mode. However, I've run into an issue with Task Manager bypassing the kiosk restrictions.

Here's the rundown: My manager requires a specific Windows Form application to run in kiosk mode, and the native kiosk setup didn't list the required application. So, I opted to replace explorer.exe with my application through the Registry Editor and utilized Group Policy Editor to disable certain features, preventing users from breaking out of the custom kiosk environment.

While this setup is functional, my manager considers it a temporary solution and a "hack" due to the manual repetition of steps for each system. I also explored scripting, but that avenue didn't pan out.

I then turned to Windows ADK. I successfully configured everything, added the executable path to the "Configure Kiosk Account and App" settings, and the application launches seamlessly. It automatically reopens if closed, and terminating it triggers a system restart - all good so far. However, Task Manager can still be accessed using a keyboard shortcut, allowing users to run explorer.exe and circumvent the kiosk mode.

I'm seeking advice on how to address this Task Manager bypass within the context of the Windows ADK and Windows 10 Enterprise. Are there specific settings or configurations I can implement to disable Task Manager or prevent the execution of explorer.exe?

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Tried a custom profile in Windows Configuration Designer but that doesn't have any effect.